# How to get inspections or static code analysis errors in intellij Idea from Intellij Idea Plugin programmatically?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, static-code-analysis

I want to create a plugin for intellij idea and in that I want to get the inspections or code analysis errors.By default intellij will show those code inspections like errors, dead code, or unused components.So I want to get those inspections pro grammatically to my plugin.I am able to create an tool button from my plugin and getting the code. Process is,

1. created plugin for intellij Idea with some actions and tools
   menu.
2. running the plugin, created separate instace  in
       intellijIdea
3. wrote some java code in new instance of intellij in editor

-->in that it will show
    inspections or errors

so I want get those inspection to my plugin.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest API for getting the inspection errors in a given set of files is [CodeSmellDetector](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/vcs-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/vcs/CodeSmellDetector.java):

```
CodeSmellDetector.getInstance(project).findCodeSmells(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what exact inspection you need, you can get it this way:

```
PhpUnusedAliasInspection inspection = new PhpUnusedAliasInspection();
InspectionManager manager = InspectionManager.getInstance(psiFile.getProject());
List<ProblemDescriptor> checked = inspection.processFile(psiFile, manager);
System.out.println("checked " + checked);
```

Outputs:

```
checked [Import 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model' is never used]
```

Where `PhpUnusedAliasInspection` may be any class that extends the `LocalInspectionTool` (you can list them all by opening the decompilled `LocalInspectionTool` class and clicking the *Subclasses* circle near the name).